# Add unblocked friend

Tags: facebook

I unblocked an old friend on Facebook and right after I tried to add them back. However, the "Add Friend" button is not available on their page anymore.

I can send a message and we have over 15 mutual friends. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? Or have you tried it on another device?

Comment: Is there any sign that the message has been received?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot add them, they have probably blocked you. So before you take action, consider if they want to be friends with you again - it might save both of you from awkward (digital) situations.

If you are willing to get in touch via FB again, you could send them a message asking to unblcok and/or add you.
Your message might end up in the "Other" folder, which people often don't read. So if there is no response, you could ask some of your mutual friends to ask your former friend to look into their "Other" folder.

Again, you probably blocked each other for a reason, so consider carefully if getting in touch again is wise.

Comment: Can you tell us how to remove that option? Because as per [Facebook Help Team](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=262922137182401&answer_id=264361363705145&rdrhc) it is not possible.

Comment: @serenesat Hm, you're right. Edited my answer.

Comment: Still it doesn't answer the question. If they have blocked OP, OP will not be able to see their profile and will not be able to send message.

Comment: @serenesat If they've blocked the OP, there is no _technical_ solution. Nor should there be one, otherwise what's the point in blocking people? The solution is to ask for unblocking or for the former friend to add the OP.

Comment: Please read question again. OP is saying he is able to send a message to that person and they have 15 mutual friends. It means OP is not blocked by that person. OP is asking why is Add Friend button not available.

Comment: @serenesat Apparently you can send messages to someone who blocked you - at least it was possible in late 2013 : https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200531929719074 .

Comment: No, you can't. read [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10205004800347248&answer_id=10205005337960688) and [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10154428134155483&answer_id=10154428162920483&rdrhc) and [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=837776812907909&answer_id=837794922906098&rdrhc)